# How to enable timeout policy with polly

Tags: c#, async-await, timeout, cancellation, polly

I'm trying out the timeout policy with polly.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        timeoutPolicy().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task timeoutPolicy()
    {
        AsyncTimeoutPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(1); // setup the timeout limit to be 1 sec

        HttpResponseMessage response = await timeoutPolicy.ExecuteAsync((ct) => LongOperation(), CancellationToken.None);

    }

    static Task<HttpResponseMessage> LongOperation()
    {
        return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // Sleep 5 seconds
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            };

        });
    }
```

I expect an exception to be thrown after 1 sec passed because that is the timeout upper limit I set up. But currently, no exception will be thrown and the method LongOperation() returns normally after around 5 secs.

Why does the timeout policy not work in this case?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the timeout policy not work in this case?

Polly's `TimeoutPolicy` exists in two modes:

- [`TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#optimistic-timeout) expects governed delegates to respond to [co-operative cancellation by CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx).
- [`TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#pessimistic-timeout) allows the calling code to *walk away from waiting for* a delegate that *doesn't respond to co-operative cancellation*.

Optimistic mode is the default, so your posted code uses this. But (a) `LongOperation()` in the posted code does not respond to co-operative cancellation; so the policy does not time it out.

Pessimistic mode with asynchronous policies is [intentionally designed only to govern delegates which conform to the normal async pattern](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#additional-notes-pessimistic-timeout-for-async-executions). `Thread.Sleep()` in the posted `LongOperation()` is fully sychronous; so your example would additionally not be timed out just by switching to `TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic`.

---

`TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic` is the best simulation of calls through `HttpClient`, as those calls do respond to `CancellationToken`.

Async timeout policy's optimistic mode timing out a long operation can be simulated with `await Task.Delay(...)` honouring a `CancellationToken`, [like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xr1A4d):

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Polly;
using Polly.Timeout;

public class Program
{ 
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        try {
            timeoutPolicy().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }

    static async Task timeoutPolicy()
    {
        var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(1); // setup the timeout limit to be 1 sec

        HttpResponseMessage response = await timeoutPolicy.ExecuteAsync((ct) => LongOperation(ct), CancellationToken.None);
    }

    static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> LongOperation(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000, token);
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're using `Optimistic` timeout which expects the delgate you're calling to respect the and respond to the cancellation token. Your delegate does not, in this case you need to use `Pessimistic` timeout to ensure your caller doesn't wait passed the defined timeout.

```
static async Task timeoutPolicy()
{
    var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(1, TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic); // setup the timeout limit to be 1 sec

    HttpResponseMessage response = await timeoutPolicy.ExecuteAsync((ct) => LongOperation(), CancellationToken.None);

}
```

[Polly Timeout](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) as stated in the docs `Optimistic` is the default.

As @moutain traveller already pointed out, optimistic timeout requires you to to pass and co-operate with the timeout cancellation. This is handled already by api calls using the `HttpClient` but in this sample case your code would look something like this:

```
static async Task timeoutPolicy()
{
    var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(1, TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic); // setup the timeout limit to be 1 sec

    HttpResponseMessage response = await timeoutPolicy.ExecuteAsync((ct) => LongOperation(ct), CancellationToken.None);

}

static Task<HttpResponseMessage> LongOperation(CancellationToken token)
{
    return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var longTask = Task.Delay(5000);
        while (!longTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
        };

    });
}
```

Comment: If I want to remain the Optimistic timeout strategy, is there a work around?  @JSteward

Comment: Yes: make the executed delegate honour co-operative cancellation. Most async calls through HttpClient do, so if that is what your test is designed to simulate, you can expect that `HttpClient.FooAsync(...)` _does_ honour co-operative cancellation.

Comment: The [Polly wiki for TimeoutPolicy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) gives a lot more detail on these issues. [This recent issue](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/623) on Polly github is on the topic of why pessimistic timeout does not cancel `Thread.Sleep()` delegates (Thread.Sleep is synchronously blocking, not async, and the async policy isn't designed to time that out).  However, if you are aiming to simulate `HttpClient.FooAsync(...)` methods, optimistic timeout via `CancellationToken` is the best simulation.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(5000, token)` can also be used, to simulate the asynchronously-blocking operation which responds to cancellation.

Comment: @mountaintraveller That's true, but it won't throw the cancellation exception. I think it just depends on what behavior is expected: quiet cancellation or cancelled exception.

Comment: @JSteward `await Task.Delay(5000, token)` will throw for cancellation if the token is cancelled within the delay. There is no quiet/silent cancellation from `Task.Delay(5000, token)` if cancellation occurs before the delay expires, _unless_ you do not observe the result of the `Task` directly (eg check `Task.IsCanceled` instead). Here [dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5dlxui), code taken straight from the [current documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay). Here pure async [dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I99tWh).